# Is "make tours of" correct?

Tags: grammar

I did a test and it had a sentence

- We make tours of haunted house. (we visit a haunted house - as i understood)

Is it correct? Other answer is "We make parts of haunted house" (We decorate our house as a haunted house)

**EDIT**
This is the passage:

> In many Western countries, people (19)_______ Halloween on October 31st. The word Halloween (20)________ from “All Hallows’ Eve”. It is the night before All Saints’ Day, a religious holiday in some parts of the world. On this night, children dress up in special costumes, put (21)________ masks, and go door to door saying “trick-or-treat” to get candy. Many people decorate their homes with paper ghosts, black cats or witches to give their houses a (22) _______ look. People also decorate their homes with jack-o-lanterns. They carve scary faces on pumpkins, and (23)_____ candles inside the pumpkins. In some places, both children and adults can make (24)______ of haunted houses. They all seem very excited about the festival.
>
> **24**.  A. parts     B. tours     C. turns     D. prizes

Comment: What is it that you are trying to say? Are you trying to say that you and your friends visit houses which are reputed to be haunted? Or perhaps you and your business associates organize tours of haunted houses. As for the "other answer", what do you mean by "parts" of a haunted house? Doors, windows, and rooms are parts of houses. Please edit your question so that it will be clearer.

Comment: We go on tours of haunted houses. To go on a tour, no making.

Comment: @Lambie - I've heard "make tours" before (though usually in the past tense, e.g., "They made tours of Italy and Greece."). It may be rare or perhaps a little stilted, but I would have no problem with, "Every year, my wife and I make tours of haunted houses."

Comment: @J.R. Make tours is not correct for tourism contexts. Every years, my wife and I go on tours of haunted houses. Now, you might say: We made a tour of the facilities. But not for trips and tourism.

Comment: @Lambie - _Chamberlain [made tours](http://www.hoakaleifoundation.org/documents/tours-made-around-o‘ahu-1826-and-1828) of Oahu in 1826 and 1828 and wrote fairly detailed descriptions of the districts he visited. Two particular travellers, who [made tours](http://curioustravellers.ac.uk/en/a-fleeting-glimpse-of-c19th-ephemeral-texts/) of Scotland and Wales in the Romantic period, Jonathan Gray and Anne Lister, have left us rich sources for this studying this aspect of tour writing_. I'd accept if you said this wording was awkward, stilted, dated, or rare, but I have trouble with "not correct."

Comment: @J.R. That is very  old fashioned lingo and does not work here. If you want to say it is grammatical, you should point out exactly how it would be used. Not in the OP's context. Also, it is referring to the 19th century. Practically historical. In modern English, we don't say make a tour in most contexts and certainly not here.

Comment: @Lambie - Oh, we are in complete agreement on old fashioned, and that it's not said in most contexts. I disagree about the "not here" part, though. Just my take on it, but I don't like to equate "seldom used" or "dated" with "incorrect" or "ungrammatical," and I don't think it does our learners any service to do so. Next thing you know, we'll get a question asking why Dickens' English is ungrammatical, based on some information a learner got here.

Comment: @J.R. I would never say: We make tours of haunted house. It sounds completely off to my ear, when I know they mean: go on tours of haunted houses or take others on tours of haunted houses, in short, run tours of haunted house.

Answer (score 1):

The original passage is on this site: https://www.kantas.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/HF14_ENGLISH_2.pdf

It said that: "In some places, both children and adults can take tours of
haunted houses.", so that I think the test we did this morning was wrong :P
My teachers is arguing over this, most of them agree with the answer "tours".
[image]

Comment: I agree that "take tours of" sounds much more like everyday English than "make tours of," even if both could be regarded as grammatical.

Comment: Take tours is correct here. Make tours would be a mistake here. For sure.

Comment: It looks like the test contains a typo.  There isn't really a good or right answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If the choice is between *tours* of the haunted house and *parts* of it, the correct answer is almost certainly *tour*s.

However, it's not idiomatic to say: *We make tours* if the meaning intended is *we offer tours*. That's to say that a company that sells tours of a haunted house would be *offering tours* rather than *making tours*.

It is people/tourists who make tours but they would be unlikely to speak of themselves as *making tours* of a haunted house. They might make a visit to a haunted house. They would make tours of a region or of castles or some other attraction - meaning to visit a number of such places.